# Laravel 5.2 session cookie driver

Tags: laravel-5, session-cookies

I have a problem with the *cookie* session driver. I need to create an app that works with only cookies. With my configuration, the session is not persisting in Laravel 5.2 with the cookie driver. If I use the *file* session driver, it works.

*.env* file:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

I also created a middleware that checks if a custom session value exists (only `handle()` function):

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //dd(session('auth')) // null
    if (!session('auth')) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I added the middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` array in *app/Http/Kernel.php*:

```php
'cookies' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckCookies::class,
```

My routes are:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'LoginController@index');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'cookies'], function () {
        Route::get('home','HomeController@index');
        Route::get('logout','HomeController@logout');
    });
});
```

Here's my `LoginController@login` method:

```php
public function login()
{
    session([
        'auth' => ['name' => 'John Doe']
    ]);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Cookie` Facades in laravel.

```
Cookie::queue('key', 'value', $minutes);
```

To make cookie forever

```
Cookie::forever('key', 'value');
```

Modify your code and try this.

`LoginController@login`

```
public function login(){
    $cookieValue=json_encode(array('name'=>'John Dow'));
    Cookie::queue('auth', $cookieValue, 60);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

`CheckCookies` Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){

        if (!Cookie::get('auth'))
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
                    return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```